# Harddrive recognized by BIOS but not by OS (possible dead drive)

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, data-recovery, water-damage

So someone threw water on my laptop, as a result, the laptop lost power (no lights of any kind blinking either anymore). I disassembled the laptop and found quite a bit of water laying on the motherboard, after drying, still not start/lights blinking.

So next I tried to put the harddrive in my desktop, but I see it in the BIOS but not windows (10) diskmanagement. Plugging it in while windows is running is the only option, because if I have it puggled in (SATA) from boot, I get this weird disk/OS corruption error (even though I set my boot sequence to use my desktop OS disk first) and the USB ports somehow stop working (so no keyboard...)..

Any steps I can take next to recover the HDD data? The disk does spinup when I connect the powercables.

Comment: May I ask why you are attempting to perform data recovery with Windows?

Comment: my idea was to just plug it in my desktop and then copy the files to another drive. My intention is to just recover the documents/photos etc, not the actual OS.

Comment: OK but we are talking about a damaged drive. You cannot just rely on it being fine and Windows happily mounting it. You would be much better off doing a proper recovery workflow with Linux.

Answer (score 0):

If you put the drive in your desktop and connected via the SATA interface you will not be able to see it in Windows, unless it was connected during the boot sequence. (Based on what you say it was not)

The best way to recover would be to place the drive into a USB enclosure and connect it AFTER the Windows booted. Since USB drives are removable, they don't have to be present during the Windows start sequence and can be connected at any time.

many enclosures available, cheaply